# How can I change the suggestion order/ scoring of the atom editor's autocomplete+ package

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

More specifically: how can I choose **which order** packages' **autocomplete suggestions** are displayed in?

Here is an example of autocomplete+'s suggestions when using the [atom-typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) package:

[image: Atom Autocomplete with the typescript package]

and one when not:

[image: Atom Autocomplete without the typescript package]

I want the `if` snippet shown in the latter image to also come first when using other packages such as the aforementioned typescript package.

I know that "[suggestions are calculated using fuzzaldrin](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/tree/92b6cefa021fe003800e522555f3d21ba763845b#features)", but also that the scoring is customizable to an extent using atom's `config.cson` file through the [`useAlternateScoring`](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/blob/92b6cefa021fe003800e522555f3d21ba763845b/package.json#L199) property among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> autocomplete-plus currently doesn't have the ability for the user to
>   manually influence the order in which items are sorted. - leedohm, moderator at atom discuss. [(source)](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-can-i-change-the-suggestion-order-scoring-of-packages-using-atom-editors-autocomplete-package/39285/2)